# Drag and Drop switch case, unreachable code?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

Why is this code unreachable and how do I fix it?

```
  public void draggingEvent() {
  image15(); 
  final int thisLetter = currentLetter;
  mImageView15.getDrawable();

  mImageView15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView15);
  mImageView15.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {


    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent de) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int action = de.getAction();
        switch(action) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            if (de.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
            v.invalidate();


            return (true);
            }


            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            v.invalidate();
            return (true);

            break;  //un reachable here
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            //ignore even for now
            if (de.getX() == 250 && de.getY() == 195) {
                mImageView17.setImageResource(thisLetter);
                v.invalidate();
            return (true);
            }
            if (de.getX() == 300 && de.getY() == 195) {
                mImageView17.setImageResource(thisLetter);
            return (true);
            } 
            break;// here
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            de.getResult();
            break; //here
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            ClipData.Item item = de.getClipData().getItemAt(thisLetter);
            v.invalidate();
            return (true);

            break; // here
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            v.invalidate();

            if (de.getResult()) {
                Log.e("it worked", "worked");
            } else {
                Log.e("failed", "sorry failed drag and drop");
            return (true);
            }
            break; //here

            default: 
                Log.e("Drag drop", "Failed to find area");
            break; // and here



    };
    return false;
    };

  });
```

Comment: Which "this" code?  What line does the error refer to?

Comment: there is no meaning to code that comes after a `return` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute any `Java` statement after return:

```
return (true);
break;  //un reachable here
```

just have `return` statement. (you have two such occurrences)

Comment: so basically call break;
return (true); ?

Comment: that would again be unreachable. Either have `return` or `break`, ideally with `switch` prefer having `break` for each case and have one `return` statement in a method.

Answer (score 2):

In general, statements after a return statement in `Java` will not be executed.

This is *almost* correct; there is an important exception which helps program stability, that being the `finally` block. For example

```
try {
    doSomething();
    return;
} finally {
    cleanUp();
}
```

the function `cleanUp()` *will* be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do `return (true)` before your `break` the `break` will never be called.